# how to integrate Wowza Streaming Engine in the .Net

Tags: c#, .net, api, wowza

I am new to Wowza Media Server.
I want to stream a video live from a .net project.
I have seen this tutorial [here](http://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?179-How-to-add-a-web-service-interface-to-Wowza-Media-Server-and-integrate-with-NET-%28dotNet%29) but I didn't get how to integrate the wowza media server api in a.net project.

Can anyone tell me steps that how to use the wowza media server api with .net??

I have searched a lot on the net but i didn't get anythiing which is usable for me.

Comment: The tutorial you link to describes the steps to create wsdl endpoints in Wowza that you can call from .Net.  If your Wowza server is not on Windows, you would need to change the wsdl command to point to the domain name/ip address of your Wowza server.  You cannot call the Wowza server api directly from .Net, for that you would need to use Java described here: http://www.wowza.com/streaming/developers